# How to copy a new line from libreoffice calc to txt?

Tags: notepad++, libreoffice, openoffice, openoffice-calc, copy

I have the following function in cell 'B2' a libreoffice calc document:

```
=CONCAT(A1,CHAR(10),A2,CHAR(10),"end")
```

Which, with in cell `A1="function plotName = getPlotName(plotData)"` and `A2="    plotName = obj.plotName;"` as expected shows:

```
function plotName = getPlotName(plotData)
    plotName = obj.plotName;
end
```

in a single cell. However when I copy that cell, by selecting it by clicking on it, pressing ctrl+c, opening notepadd++ and pressing ctrl+v, the new line character is not copied.

If I copy the text, and paste special>Text, and then copy paste that in notepad++, it indeed copies the enters. Hence I thought of making an extra cell, in `C2=TEXT(B2)` but that returns error 511.

How can I ensure the new line character, is in fact copied to e.g. notepad++?

LibreOffice Calc Version: 6.3.2.2 (x64)
Notepad++ V7.8.1
Windows 10

Comment: Works for me, libreOffice 6.3.2.2 (x64); Notepad++ 7.8.1 64bit

Comment: Thank you, I did not test my original MWE, my apologies. The original MWE lost the problem because it was too simplified, I confirmed the original MWE works indeed like you said. Hence, I updated my question (and the MWE) to the actual text. I think the problem is induced by the 4 "manual" spaces. I tested the updated MWE and it does not work.

Comment: I assume you're working in Windows?  Try CRLF instead of just LF: `=CONCAT(A1,CHAR(13),CHAR(10),A2,CHAR(13),CHAR(10),"end")

Comment: That is a correct assumption. If I had been more consistent and complete I might have realized it may have been the Windows/Unix/Mac line endings. Thank you, I was not thorough enough and did not look up what CHAR(10) exactly means. You can post your solution as answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the issue was that Windows uses CRLF rather than LF for line endings.  For Windows, use:

```
=CONCAT(A1,CHAR(13),CHAR(10),A2,CHAR(13),CHAR(10),"end")
```